# Mulesoft Scheduler is executing twice

Tags: cron, mule, mule-studio, mulesoft, mule4

I have a flow having scheduler as source.
This scheduler is having a cron expression to get it executed 15th of every month at 4 am.

```
0 0 4 15 * ? *
```

But somehowe this flow is getting executed twice. 15th as well as on 16th on the same time.
Below are the cloudHub Log entries.

There are no multiple scheduler and application is working on 1 Worker with .2vCore.

Please let me if anyone faced this issue before.

Mule RunTime Version : 4.4.0
Same issue is coming in Development environment as well.

( I have removed confidential information from log info )

```
[2022-08-15 04:00:07.898] INFO    org.mule.extension.jsonlogger.JsonLogger [[MuleRuntime].uber.11911:fifteenthDayOfMonth-scheduler-flow.BLOCKING @72141012]: event:c0603230-1c4e-11ed-b2fc-1264ce2d1c7b {
  "correlationId" : "c06031230-1c41e-11ed-b2fc-1264c1e2d1c7b231",
  "message" : "Begin Schedular flow",
  "tracePoint" : "START",
  "priority" : "INFO",
  "elapsed" : 0,
  "locationInfo" : {
    "lineInFile" : "51",
    "component" : "json-logger:logger",
    "fileName" : "schedulers.xml",
    "rootContainer" : "fifteenthDayOfMonth-scheduler-flow"
  },
  "timestamp" : "2022-08-15T04:00:07.897Z",
  "content" : { },
  "applicationName" : "biz-prc-ent-finance-bulk-api-prod",
  "applicationVersion" : "v1",
  "environment" : "prod"
}

[2022-08-16 04:00:03.577] INFO    org.mule.extension.jsonlogger.JsonLogger [[MuleRuntime].uber.12580:fifteenthDayOfMonth-scheduler-flow.BLOCKING @72141012]: event:e8364f00-1d17-11ed-b2fc-1264ce2d1c7b {
  "correlationId" : "e8364f006-1d17-11ed-b2f6c-1264ce26d1c7b12334",
  "message" : "Begin Schedular flow",
  "tracePoint" : "START",
  "priority" : "INFO",
  "elapsed" : 0,
  "locationInfo" : {
    "lineInFile" : "51",
    "component" : "json-logger:logger",
    "fileName" : "schedulers.xml",
    "rootContainer" : "fifteenthDayOfMonth-scheduler-flow"
  },
  "timestamp" : "2022-08-16T04:00:03.575Z",
  "content" : { },
  "applicationName" : "biz-prc-ent-finance-bulk-api-prod",
  "applicationVersion" : "v1",
  "environment" : "prod"
}
```

flow xml

```
<flow name="workday-netsuite-journal-fifteenthDayOfMonth-scheduler-flow" doc:id="79a57c74-36ea-48db-ba49-3c54157fc6e0">
        <scheduler doc:name="Schedule @ every fifteenthDayOfMonth" doc:id="666bf73a-82ad-42f8-8775-d84ce86b542e" >
            <scheduling-strategy >
                <cron expression="${cron.journal.fifteenthDayOfMonth}" />
            </scheduling-strategy>
        </scheduler>
        <json-logger:logger doc:name="Begin Schedular flow - Workday Journal Sync to Netsuite " doc:id="eb92ea96-8285-4403-a9bd-c4425022d07e" config-ref="JSON_Logger_Config" message="Begin Schedular flow - Workday Journal Sync to Netsuite "/>
        <flow-ref doc:name="getlookdatafromnetsuite" doc:id="b6917c50-ed4b-414d-aa50-cb7994203218" name="getlookdatafromnetsuite"/>
        <set-payload value="#['regularrun-getworkdaydataflow']" doc:name="Set Payload" doc:id="3f9d33a5-6a56-427c-b58b-6efdc6d1dfdd" />
        <flow-ref doc:name='workday-netsuite-impl-flow' doc:id="14f6171c-ce9d-4c68-8f28-e1437c652097" name="workday-netsuite-impl-flow"/>
        <json-logger:logger doc:name="End Of Schedular flow - Workday Journal Sync to Netsuite " doc:id="852a1da4-0be4-4461-b60f-1a3fb7b23f52" config-ref="JSON_Logger_Config" message="End Of Schedular flow - Workday Journal Sync to Netsuite " tracePoint="END"/>
        <error-handler ref="workday-netsuite-implError_Handler_Propagate" />
    </flow>
```

Comment: Please share the flow with the scheduler and explain what the flow is doing.

Comment: hi @aled, update the description with the flow xml.

Answer (score 2):

A CloudHub scheduler can [re trigger if it takes too much time to complete the flow execution](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Scheduler-re-triggers-after-12-hours-and-transactions-run-in-parallel). Review the total time of execution. If there are bottlenecks preventing the event to finish a thread dump could be useful for analysis.